# Tablesorter — How can I sort a column by first or last name (both ascending) rather than toggling between ascending and decending?

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I want to use [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) to sort a column (column contains first name + last name) so that clicking the header toggles between sorting by first name and sorting by last name, both in ascending order.
I have found a jsfiddle ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3393/)) that is very close to what I want to do.

```
$(function () {

    var $cell;
    $('#games').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textExtraction: {
            0: function (node, table, cellIndex) {
                var $n = $(node);
                // add semi-colon between values
                return $n.find('.name').text() + ';' + $n.find('.perc').text();
            }
        },
        textSorter: function (a, b) {
            var x = a.split(';'),
                y = b.split(';'),
                i = $cell && $cell.is('.active') ? 1 : 0;
            return $.tablesorter.sortNatural($.trim(x[i]), $.trim(y[i]));
        },
        initialized: function () {
            $cell = $('#games').find('.percSort');
            $cell.click(function () {
                // activate percentage sort
                $cell.addClass('active');
                return false;
            }).closest('th').click(function () {
                // clicking on header outside of percSort
                // inactivates the percentage sort
                $cell.removeClass('active');
            });

        }
    });

});
```

It toggles between sorting by name (ascending) and sorting by percentage (descending) when the header is clicked. However, in my case, I want it to toggle between sorting first name (ascending) and last name (ascending). I want both sorts to be ascending and I'm not sure how to modify this code to make that happen. If nothing else, I can make them separate columns instead and give up on this, but I think it would look better to have the full name displayed together.

I tried looking through the [documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), but I wasn't able to figure out a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the html structure as it is (), and change just its text-content:

```html
<h3>Click on the "%" sign to sort the first column by percentages;<br>Click outside to sort by name</h3>

<table id="games">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname <span class="percSort">&nbsp;Lastname&nbsp;</span>

            </th>
            <th>Numeric</th>
            <th>Animals</th>
            <th>Sites</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="gamename">
                <div style="width:66%;background-color: hsla(84,100%,50%,0.7);"></div>
<span class="name">Alice</span>

<span class="perc">Petterson</span>

            </th>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Koala</td>
            <td>http://www.google.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="gamename">
                <div style="width:46%;background-color: hsla(34,100%,50%,0.7);"></div>
<span class="name">Peter</span>

<span class="perc">Brook</span>

            </th>
            <td>234</td>
            <td>Ox</td>
            <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: In my question I stated that I would like both sorts to be ascending. In the example, the percentages are sorted in descending order, so modifying it like this would just sort the last names in descending order rather than ascending.

Comment: Try to swap the place of x and y that way in your code by : return $.tablesorter.sortNatural($.trim(y[i]), $.trim(x[i]))

Comment: Otherwise, you should consider modifying the original function sortNatural defined here: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js and bind this modified version to your html head tag

Comment: I like the idea of swapping the x and y when it is sorting by last name. Thanks for the help!